# Passing variables in Business Basic appears to not be working

Tags: basic, business-basic

The following code calls a program I made that automatically creates an input field with brackets on either side at a certain length.

`C$` is a standard variable we use in all our programs in the business;
the length is `10`;
`Age:` is the label; 
the x coordinate is `1`;
the y coordinate is `1` and
`IN$` is the variable for the input statement

```
3020 CALL "SCOINPUT",C$,10,"AGE:   ",1,1,IN$
```

The following program makes the input line:

```
0100 REM 100 - SCOINPUT - CREATES AN INPUT LINE WITH BRACKETS AND TO A CERTAIN
0100: SIZE
0150 SETERR 15000
0155 ENTER C$,INSIZE,LABEL$,X,Y,IN$
0160 LET LABEL$=CVS(LABEL$,7)
0170 LET EBRAK=X+LEN(LABEL$)+SIZE+2
0300 IF INSIZE<>0 THEN GOTO 0400 ELSE GOTO 0500
0400 PRINT @(X,Y),LABEL$+" [",@(EBRAK,Y),"]",
0410 INPUT (0,SIZ=INSIZE)@(X+LEN(LABEL$)+2,Y),"",IN$
15000 SETERR 15010; EXIT
15010 END
```

When the line is printed, everything is in the correct place, however the length isn't limited to 10 like it should be... anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LEN` option rather than `SIZ` for restricting input

```
0410 INPUT (0,LEN=INSIZE)@(X+LEN(LABEL$)+2,Y),"",IN$
```